# Condition Shift in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I am trying to count up a number during a sequence change.

The number shall always be +1, when changing from the negative to the positive range.

Here the code:

```
data = {'a':  [-1,-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-2,-2,-3,6,3,6,7,-1,-5,-7,1,34,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data)


df['p'] = df.a > 0
df['g'] = (df['p'] != df['p'].shift()).cumsum()
```

This is the output:

```
0  -1  False  1
1  -1  False  1
2  -2  False  1
3  -3  False  1
4   4   True  2
5   5   True  2
6   6   True  2
7  -2  False  3
8  -2  False  3
9  -3  False  3
10  6   True  4
11  3   True  4
12  6   True  4
13  7   True  4
14 -1  False  5
```

I need an output that looks like this:

```
0  -1  False  1
1  -1  False  1
2  -2  False  1
3  -3  False  1
4   4   True  2
5   5   True  2
6   6   True  2
7  -2  False  2
8  -2  False  2
9  -3  False  2
10  6   True  3
11  3   True  3
12  6   True  3
13  7   True  3
14 -1  False  3
```

Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df['p'] = df.a > 0
df['g'] = ((df['p'] != df['p'].shift()) & df['p']).cumsum() + 1
```

Another idea is filter by mask in column `p`, forward filling missing values replace `NaN` by first group and add `1`:

```
df['p'] = df.a > 0
df['g'] = ((df['p'] != df['p'].shift()))[df['p']].cumsum()
df['g'] = df['g'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int) + 1
```

Solution with differencies, without helper `p` column:

```
df['g'] = df.a.gt(0).view('i1').diff().gt(0).cumsum().add(1)
```

---

```
print (df)
     a      p  g
0   -1  False  1
1   -1  False  1
2   -2  False  1
3   -3  False  1
4    4   True  2
5    5   True  2
6    6   True  2
7   -2  False  2
8   -2  False  2
9   -3  False  2
10   6   True  3
11   3   True  3
12   6   True  3
13   7   True  3
14  -1  False  3
15  -5  False  3
16  -7  False  3
17   1   True  4
18  34   True  4
19   5   True  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.sign` and `diff`, `gt`, and `cumsum`

```
s = np.sign(df.a)
df['g'] = s.diff().gt(0).cumsum() + 1

Out[255]:
     a      p  g
0   -1  False  1
1   -1  False  1
2   -2  False  1
3   -3  False  1
4    4   True  2
5    5   True  2
6    6   True  2
7   -2  False  2
8   -2  False  2
9   -3  False  2
10   6   True  3
11   3   True  3
12   6   True  3
13   7   True  3
14  -1  False  3
15  -5  False  3
16  -7  False  3
17   1   True  4
18  34   True  4
19   5   True  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df["g"] = (df.p.astype(int).diff() > 0).astype(int).cumsum() + 1
```

output:

```
     a      p  g
0   -1  False  1
1   -1  False  1
2   -2  False  1
3   -3  False  1
4    4   True  2
5    5   True  2
6    6   True  2
7   -2  False  2
8   -2  False  2
9   -3  False  2
10   6   True  3
11   3   True  3
12   6   True  3
13   7   True  3
14  -1  False  3
15  -5  False  3
16  -7  False  3
17   1   True  4
18  34   True  4
19   5   True  4
```